# Using regex for doing string operation

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string

```
String s="my name is ${name}. My roll no is  ${rollno} "
```

I want to do string operations to update the `name` and `rollno` using a method.

```
public void name(String name, String roll)
{
String new = s.replace(" ${name}", name).replace(" ${rollno}", roll);


}
```

Can we achieve the same using some other means like using regex to change after first `"$"` and similarly for the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `Matcher#appendReplacement` or `Matcher#replaceAll` (with Java 9+):

A more generic version:

```java
String s="my name is ${name}. My roll no is ${rollno} ";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^{}]+)\\}").matcher(s);
Map<String,String> replacements = new HashMap();
replacements.put("name","John");
replacements.put("rollno","123");
StringBuffer replacedLine = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
if (replacements.get(m.group(1)) != null)
    m.appendReplacement(replacedLine, replacements.get(m.group(1)));
else
    m.appendReplacement(replacedLine, m.group());
}
m.appendTail(replacedLine);
System.out.println(replacedLine.toString());
// => my name is John. My roll no is 123
```

Java 9+ solution:

```java
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^{}]+)\\}").matcher(s);
String result = m2.replaceAll(x -> 
    replacements.get(x.group(1)) != null ? replacements.get(x.group(1)) : x.group());
System.out.println( result );
// => my name is John. My roll no is 123
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/mhjJYX).

The regex is `\$\{([^{}]+)\}`:

- `\$\{` - a `${` char sequence
- `([^{}]+)` - Group 1 (`m.group(1)`): any one or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `\}` - a `}` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vIgvI8/1).

Comment: Thankyou so much for the detailed explanation.
You made it quite clear for me :-)

Comment: Hi @Wiktoe I have a doubt what is m.group(1) used for?

Comment: @Hannah `m.group(1)` is a method of `m` Matcher object that gets the string value of the first capturing group in the regular expression.